# RShiny Reactive data frame manipulation in dplyr using selected input

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I can't make my dplyr code work within Shiny.

I'm trying to manipulate a data frame dependent on "input" selected by the user. I would like to use a drop down menu in the **ui**, but then can't make it work in **server** (when using dplyr `select()`). I've made it work with "action buttons", but that makes for very repetitive code (each `observeEvent()` essentially has the same code).

I'm adapting code written in RMarkdown in which I change the definition of a `TARGET` variable at the beginning of the notebook that affects all subsequent models, plots, and tables when I re-knit. By commenting In/Out one line, I produce results for several different target variables (which share some, but not all data). I would like to implement this in Shiny for self-service by other users.

```
# I would like to do it "this" way, but it doesn't work

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(lubridate)


df <- airquality %>% 
    mutate(date = make_datetime(day = Day, month = Month), 
           Ozone1 = Ozone + 1, Temp1 = Temp + 1,
           Ozone_predictor = Ozone / 2, Temp_predictor = Temp / 2) %>% 
    select(date, everything(), -Month, -Day)


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Title
    titlePanel("New York AirQuality Measurements"),

    # Input Selection used to build dataframe
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "target", 
                        label = "Choose a prediction target for visualization", 
                        choices = list("Ozone", "Ozone1", "Temp")
            )
        ), 

        # Plot
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot", height = "1200px")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    df <- reactive({
        if(input$target == "Ozone"){
            df <- df %>%
                select(-Ozone1, -contains("Temp")) %>% 
                tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
            if(input$target == "Ozone1"){
                df <- df %>%
                    select(-Ozone, -contains("Temp")) %>% 
                    tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
            }else{
                df <- df %>%
                    select(-contains("Ozone")) %>% 
                    tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
            }
        }
    })


    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(df(), aes(date, value)) +
            geom_line() +
            facet_wrap(key ~ ., scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
            labs(y = "", x = "") +
            theme_classic()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



# This does work... but is repetitive and may be problematic 
# if I have more target variables.

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(lubridate)


df <- airquality %>%
    mutate(date = make_datetime(day = Day, month = Month),
           Ozone1 = Ozone + 1, Temp1 = Temp + 1,
           Ozone_predictor = Ozone / 2, Temp_predictor = Temp / 2) %>%
    select(date, everything(), -Month, -Day)


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Title
    titlePanel("New York AirQuality Measurements"),

    # Action buttons to define dataframe selection
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton(inputId = "Ozone", label = "Ozone"),
            actionButton(inputId = "Ozone1", label = "Ozone One"),
            actionButton(inputId = "Temp", label = "Temperature")),

        # Plot
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot", height = "1200px")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(
        data = df %>%
            tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
    )

    observeEvent(input$Ozone,
                 { rv$data <-
                     df %>%
                     select(-Ozone1, -contains("Temp")) %>%
                     tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
                 })

    observeEvent(input$Ozone1,
                 { rv$data <-
                     df %>%
                     select(-Ozone, -contains("Temp")) %>%
                     tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
                 })

    observeEvent(input$Temp,
                 { rv$data <-
                     df %>%
                     select(-contains("Ozone")) %>%
                     tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
                 })


    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data = rv$data, aes(date, value)) +
            geom_line() +
            facet_wrap(key ~ ., scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
            labs(y = "", x = "") +
            theme_minimal()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error: no applicable method for 'select_'applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (main) problem was, that you define a reactive `df` which has the same name as the non-reactive data frame in your global environment `df` which is created at the start-up of your app. This seemed to got things mixed up. I changed the name of the reactive to `data`.

Within your reactive the `if` statements were not connected with each other, I did that using `else if`. Further you do not need to assign `<-` the data to a temporary variable (in your case `df`). And if you use assign, you need to call this temporary object at the end of the reactive (or at the end of each if/else statement).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(lubridate)


df <- airquality %>% 
  mutate(date = make_datetime(day = Day, month = Month), 
         Ozone1 = Ozone + 1, Temp1 = Temp + 1,
         Ozone_predictor = Ozone / 2, Temp_predictor = Temp / 2) %>% 
  select(date, everything(), -Month, -Day)


ui <- fluidPage(

  # Title
  titlePanel("New York AirQuality Measurements"),

  # Input Selection used to build dataframe
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "target", 
                  label = "Choose a prediction target for visualization", 
                  choices = list("Ozone", "Ozone1", "Temp")
      )
    ), 

    # Plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot", height = "1200px")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({

    if(input$target == "Ozone"){
      df %>%
        select(-Ozone1, -contains("Temp")) %>% 
        tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
      } else if(input$target == "Ozone1"){
        df %>%
          select(-Ozone, -contains("Temp")) %>% 
          tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
      }else if (input$target == "Temp") {
        df %>%
          select(-contains("Ozone")) %>% 
          tidyr::gather(key = key, value = value, -date)
      }


  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(), aes(date, value)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(key ~ ., scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
      labs(y = "", x = "") +
      theme_classic()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```